# SonarQube Multilanguage project for C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube

I'm trying to setup a Multilanguage project in SonarQube with Jenkinsfile consisting of a Java and a C# part. Every part works fine for itself in SonarQube.

But when I run the SonarQubeScanner and afterwards the SonarScanner for MSBuild with the same ProjectKey and Name, the Project will be overwritten, so I just will see the C# part in SonarQube.

Is there a way to get C# code and Java code into one single SonarQube-project?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a supported use-case at the moment. You will have to split the analysis into 2 projects.